# Past simple tense

Tags: grammar, meaning, difference, past-tense

He told me that the meeting was in the hall before I had even framed the question.

Could I change above explanation as follow

He told me that the meeting was in the hall before I even framed the question at first.

Comment: It would be fine to use Simple Past *(**I framed**)* instead of Past Perfect *(**I had framed**)* in your context. But ***at first*** is completely out of place in your second example. And "framing questions" is unnecessary verbosity - just say *...before I['d] even **asked***.